# c# login using xampp and php in UNITY

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

Hello everyone so i was developing a game with login in Unity 5, I successfully manage to create a registration form but the login always keeps saying "login failed" even though the username and password are correct. I feel like my code only recognize the "else" statement because I already tried switching my conditions

here is the C# code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DataLogin : MonoBehaviour {
public InputField inputUsername1;
public InputField inputPassword1;
public static string Username;
public static string Password;


string UserURL1 = "http://localhost/login.php";

void Start(){

}
void Update(){

}
//  void OnMouseDown(Button insertButton){
//      InsertData(inputUsername, inputPassword);
//  }
public void Button_Click1(){
    StartCoroutine(LoginData (inputUsername1, inputPassword1));

}
IEnumerator LoginData(InputField inputUsername1, InputField inputPassword1){
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    form.AddField ("username", inputUsername1.text);
    form.AddField ("password", inputPassword1.text);

    WWW www = new WWW (UserURL1, form);
    yield return www;

    if (www.text [0] == '0') {
        Debug.Log ("User Login Success.");
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("User Login Failed.");
   }
  }
}
```

here is the php code

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "table_test";

    $user = $_POST["username"];
    $pass = $_POST["password"];

     // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = " SELECT * FROM test WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$pass'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['username'] = $user && $row['password'] = $pass) {
          echo ("Login Successfully");
        } else {
          echo ("Login Failed");
        }
     }
   }
?>
```

Comment: `if ($row['username'] = $user && $row['password'] = $pass)` - php uses `==` or even `===` for comparison.

Comment: also i think you have to use your local ip address here `string UserURL1 = "http://localhost/login.php";` instead of localhost

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if the result from the php script's first character is '0'.

However, in your PhP script you never return '0'. You either return `"Login Successfully"` or `"Login Failed"`.

So i suggest you either check for that in your if-statement or you log the actual response from the server:

```
Debug.Log (www.text);
```

Although i'm not sure if that is the correct syntax, since you are using an older version of Unity.

Also, your Php script is vulnerable to SQL Injection. [Check this post for more information on that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)